# How do I use a chi squared test for homogeneity/other statistical method for this situation?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I am performing analysis on data of ~8,000 patients who have COVID. This is my scenario. I have information of each patient being classified as either severe or non-severe in how COVID-19 affected them. I also have a set of all the mutations that each patient had.

Thus, I generated frequencies as such:
Frequency = P(Having Mutation X and a Severe Clinical Response) divided by P(Mutation X). I did this for all mutations that have at least 30 patients to satisfy proper conditions for the statistical test.

From my original dataset of 8,000 patients, I know that about 1,000 had a severe clinical response. Thus, my null hypothesis is that for any given mutation the frequency, as calculated above, should be equal to 1/8 if it has no correlation to a severe response to COVID. What is the best way to perform a statistical test that can compare the severity frequency of each mutation to the population proportion (1/8) and also account for sample size (i.e. if one mutation has a frequency of 0.9, but only 30 patients have it, it's likely not as significant as a mutation which 5,000 patients have even if the frequency is lower, at 0.5).

I am thinking of doing a chi-squared test for homogeneity but am not sure about how to go about it because I don't think it compares to the proportion of the entire dataset and I'm not sure if it accounts for sample size either.

I've already performed feature selection with machine learning so I am solely looking to analyze the data with a statistical technique. Thanks.

Comment: If you have performed feature selection, you cannot apply classical tests. You need to look into selective inference or post-selection inference. This might be a good place to get started: https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-statistics-100421-044639. You should post this on the stats SE if you need more help.

Comment: I'm not looking to perform statistical tests on the feature selection. I was just mentioning that I'm not looking to do feature selection again. The statistical sets I'm using are on the original dataset (pre-feature selection).

Comment: Yes, but you are testing the significance of features that you selected. This is precisely the issue that post selection tries to address.

Comment: To give an example, suppose you have linear model, $y=X\beta$ and $\beta = 0 \in \mathbb R^{100}$. Now, it is unlikely for $\lvert \hat \beta \rvert_j$ to be large for any individual $j$, but rather unlikely for at least a few $\hat \beta_j$ out of $100$ to be large. If you a priori fix which index $j$ to test, there is no issue with the size of your test. If, however, you perform feature selection, then you will simply pick the coefficients with the largest values, and then you test them, and of course you get significance.

Comment: No, I'm planning on testing the significance of the original dataset (pre-feature selection). The feature selection has nothing to do with this. I was just mentioning that because I wasn't looking for a solution with feature selection again - just looking for a statistical test this time. Thanks!

Comment: And the mutation X you are looking at is not a function  of the data?

Comment: The data is sorted as such:
There are 8,000 patients and each patient has a set of mutations: Mutation X, Mutation Y, Mutation Z, etc. Each patient has a different amount of mutations. We also have data about whether each patient had a severe response or non severe response.